# Areas is not working in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

i tried to split my module in areas 
my modules are 
   1. Login
   2. User Admin
   3. Master

i created the area and my first start up page is (area = login, controller = login, action = loginpage)

My code route config codes are

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "SRR.Areas.Login.Controllers" }
        );


    }
}
```

LoginAreaRegistration.cs

```
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Login";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        //Trace.WriteLine("Login");
        context.MapRoute(
            "Login_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "SRR.Areas.Login.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

UserAdminAreaRegistration.cs

```
public class UserAdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "UserAdmin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "UserAdmin_default",
            "UserAdmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Menu", action = "MenuPrivilages", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "SRR.Areas.UserAdmin.Controllers" }

        );
    }
}
```

Here my starting page login is coming fine but the useradmin module is views are not showing it through the error has "The resource cannot be found".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I believe is you have the controller 'login' and action method 'login' twice, one in area and other in root. So that the namespace must differ but you have the similar namespace for both the routes which is wrong. By default it is not necessary to specify the namespace for the default route since it'll map the root files. This might be the reason why the application could not find which log in to call.

Comment: Yes boss i can changed it different name then also it showing error like this "~/Areas/Login/Views/SRRLogin/LoginPage.aspx".

Comment: yes boss, please help me. you are right i given same name for area, controller and action but now i changed it then also it show cannot found the resources

Comment: @KarthiDinaa can you update the modified source code in your query?

Comment: No venkat but i change just controller name Login to SRRLogin and action method Login to LoginPage thats it and i am not having any controller in root folder i directly tring to access the area controller as my start up page

Comment: But by default you can set the controller|action from the root as the default route. That is why it says resource cannot be found, upto my knowledge I would say if you want to show the action from the area you need to redirect to that action from the default action method.

Answer (score 1):

Login area registration missies the area specification in the pattern definition; change "{controller}/{action}/{id}" to "Login/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

What happens if your remove the namespaces constraints from the route registrations? Are the controllers  (all of them Login and UserAdmin) in correct namespaces? I guess the Login controllers are showing because of the missing area specification as i mentioned above and the Login* controllers aren't in the correct namespaces.

You RegisterRoutes method misses a line before the default route registration:

```
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Comment: if i change "Login/{controller}/{action}/{id}" in LoginAreaRegistration class the my login page also not come it showing error as "~/View/Lodin/Login.cshtml"

Comment: Yes i know as i metntioned above. And "Lodin" or "Login"?

Comment: Yes Your are right it will takes always Login.*controller then how to slove it

Comment: As i said before: correct the namespaces and add the AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); line to the area registration.

Comment: Ya correct it and add AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); in Application_Start() function then also its not working